# Создание процессов в С++11

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, c++11

Пишу программу, используя С++11. Появилась необходимость создать новый процесс. Подскажите, есть аналог функции `CreateProcess` в *С++11* или все же необходимо использовать *WinAPI*?

Также необходимо создать проекцию файла. Как сделать это в *WinAPI* знаю, но вот в *С++11* не представляю. Как возможно это реализовать?

Comment: В стандарте С++11 нет понятия процесс

Comment: как вариант есть boost process, однако это очень странная библиотека

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартная библиотека ориентируется на некую усредненную поддержку ОС, поэтому даже потоки в ней определены упрощенно (например, нет возможности управлять приоритетами потоков). Управление процессами в разных ОС различается гораздо сильнее, поэтому вряд ли возможно вывести какой-то разумный общий API ([Boost.Process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/process.html) выглядит как-то сомнительно, да и возможности там очень урезанные). Так что функцией [system](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) все и ограничивается (еще `_spawn`, но это нестандартная).

Та же самая проблема и с файловыми функциями. Из-за требования переносимости стандартная библиотека включает только самые примитивные средства работы с файлами. Даже для обычного асинхронного В/В приходится использовать API системы, а про отображаемые файлы и говорить нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Создание процесса - см. функции [`spawnxxx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/20y988d2.aspx), это их работа. Это не стандарт C++11, но POSIX.

А вот проекция файла  - этого нет ни в C++, ни в POSIX.

Comment: `_spawn` нет в стандарте, так что ее скорее нужно рассматривать как функцию системы.

Comment: В стандарте языка - да, но в POSIX есть. А это тоже стандарт. Никого же не смущают постоянные `getch()` из `conio.h` - так почему должен смущать скажем `spawnl` из `process.h`?

Comment: В принципе верно, но MS очень свободно относится к стандартам (официальная политика, кстати), а к стандарту POSIX особенно. Если я правильно помню, он у них реализован частично и с отклонениями. То есть стандарт он стандарт, но полагаться на это не стоит. Это не конкретно про `_spawn`, а вообще замечание.

Comment: Это конечно никому не интересно но меня например смущают - я не знаю ни что это ни из какой библиотеки это (`getch` и `conio.h`). `getc` и `getchar` знаю, а откуда берутся в примерах студентов `conio.h` для меня всегда было загадкой. Если верить странице на википедии о заголовке process.h - он не описан ни в ANSI/C ни в POSIX: [пруф](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process.h)

Comment: @vegorov, ну что касается `getch`, то в MSDN о ней всего одна строка: "*This POSIX function is deprecated beginning in Visual C++ 2005. Use the ISO C++ conformant _getch instead.*". У меня о POSIX вообще сложилось впечатление, что MS настроена все это в конечном итоге выкинуть. А откуда у студентов `conio.h` так что тут непонятного - передирают из интернета и друг у друга.